# Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js, google-visualization

I am getting an error `Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"` 
I'm using `chart.js` and `google timeline` for representation purpose.
But actually I am selecting some data between a date range `start_date` and `end_date` then it's passing to the function.
but there it's showing the error.

```
function addMarker(markerDate, container, dateRangeStart, dateRangeEnd, options, formatDate) {
    var baseline;
    var baselineBounds;
    var chartElements;
    var markerLabel;
    var markerLine;
    var markerSpan;
    var svg;
    var timeline;
    var timelineUnit;
    var timelineWidth;
    var timespan;

    baseline = null;
    timeline = null;
    svg = null;
    markerLabel = null;
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        svg = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        timeline = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        baseline = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        markerLabel = chartElements[0].cloneNode(true);
    }
    if ((svg === null) || (timeline === null) || (baseline === null) || (markerLabel === null) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() < dateRangeStart.min.getTime()) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() > dateRangeEnd.max.getTime())) {
        return;
    }
```

in console, it shows the error is in this part.

```
if (chartElements.length > 0) {
        markerLabel = chartElements[0].cloneNode(true);
    }
```

Comment: Oh that is great...It would also be great if you could give some more details

Comment: I've edited my code, please look through it